# shuffling after splitting data or before that?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, shuffle

I want shuffle my dataset, I saw in the github in this [code](https://github.com/kabkabm/defensegan/blob/master/datasets/mnist.py), shuffle is after splitting data, my question is whats deffrence between shuffling after spliting with when we don't shuffle it??? which one is correct?? I think it should be before splitting.

```
    if split == 'train':
        images = train_images[:50000]
        labels = train_labels[:50000]
    elif split == 'val':
        images = train_images[50000:60000]
        labels = train_labels[50000:60000]
    elif split == 'test':
        images = test_images
        labels = test_labels

    if randomize:
        rng_state = np.random.get_state()
        np.random.shuffle(images)
        np.random.set_state(rng_state)
        np.random.shuffle(labels)
```

or

```
    if randomize:
        rng_state = np.random.get_state()
        np.random.shuffle(images)
        np.random.set_state(rng_state)
        np.random.shuffle(labels)

    if split == 'train':
        images = train_images[:50000]
        labels = train_labels[:50000]
    elif split == 'val':
        images = train_images[50000:60000]
        labels = train_labels[50000:60000]
    elif split == 'test':
        images = test_images
        labels = test_labels
```

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense to shuffle the dataset only *before* the split

If you shuffle the dataset after the split, the shuffle will not affect the performance, you are changing only the instances order

Basically, if you shuffle before the split, you obtain different sets for your training / validation / test sets

If you shuffle after the split, you have always the same sets.

---

Example:

1) shuffling before split

```
my_set = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
shuffle(my_set)
# ["B", "A", "D", "E", "C", "G", "F"]
train = my_set[:3] # ["B", "A", "D"]
val = my_set[3:5] # ["E", "C"]
test = my_set[5:-1] # ["G", "F"]
```

2) shuffling after split

```
my_set = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
train = my_set[:3] # ["A", "B", "C"]
val = my_set[3:5] # ["D", "E"]
test = my_set[5:-1] # ["F", "G"]
new_train = shuffle(train, inplace=False)
new_val = shuffle(val, inplace=False)
new_test = shuffle(test, inplace=False)
set(new_train) == set(train) #True
set(new_val) == set(val) #True
set(new_test) == set(test) #True
```

**NOTE:** When training the set order may affect the performance, for example when you use algorithms in which you use batches and derivative approaches